# Open in our app link is broken for posts from localized meta sites

Tags: bug, android-app, mobile-web, localization

Trying to open [this post](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4270/176217) from mobile web via link "читать сообщение в приложении!" in the Android app:

> [image: e]

opens *Google Play Store* with app instead of app inself:

> [image: re]

Same behaviour for all posts from meta localized sites: pt, es, jp, ru.

- App Version: 1.0.89
- Device Manufacturer: LGE
- Device Model: LG-H860
- OS Version: 6.0.1 (1634100298931)